# Define useSelector type from external file React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there any way I could define useSelector `<TRootState, string>` in external file and apply it directly inside Component's file?

External file:

```
export type TUser = <TRootState, string> // not working
```

Component's file:

```
import { TUser } from "./pathToFile"
const user = useSelector<TUser>(selectUser)
```

I'm able to define the type with:

```
const user = useSelector<TRootState, string>(selectUser)
```

But I like to define it once and apply it in every file that needs it.
How it could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this in some my projects by creating a strongly typed wrapper around `useSelector` that I require instead.

```
// selectors.ts
import { useSelector as reduxUseSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { StoreState } from './store'

/** Application specific strongly typed wrapper around redux's useSelector(). */
export function useSelector<T>(fn: (state: StoreState) => T): T {
  return reduxUseSelector(fn)
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
import { useSelector } from './selectors'

function Component() {
  const foo = useSelector(state => state.foo) // state is typed here
  //...
}
```

And I would then say that `selectUser` should instead be a hook that calls this version of `useSelector` for you.

```
import { useSelector } from './selectors'

export function useCurrentUser(): User {
  return useSelector(state => state.user)
}

function Component() {
  const user = useCurrentUser()
  //...
}
```

Comment: Is there any downside on not using the additional parameter "string" explicitly?

Comment: I don't think so. In fact I would argue omitting it is way better. That second parameter is the return type of the selector, and this version uses a generic to infer that. This way it lets the type of your store implicitly come through to your local variables.